# Compile *.scss file with sass-maven-plugin when restart TomCat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, sass

I configured my pom.xml to use sass-maven-plugin, but I want to execute the compilation everytime I save the style.scss.
With this configuration is necessary to open a windows terminal and run "maven clean install", and this terminal needs to be opened to compile the SCSS file in real time.

It´s possible to do this using only Eclipse?

My pom.xml inside my project is like this one:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/scss</directory>
                        </source>
                        <destination>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/css</destination>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <sassOptions>
                    <cache>false</cache>
                    <always_update>true</always_update>
                </sassOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

For auto compiling run sass-maven-plugin's watch goal:

```
mvn sass:watch
```

Check this tutorial for more: http://cleancodejava.com/auto-compile-sass-stylesheets-with-maven/

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is based on the guide at this page: http://www.crazed.org.uk/2012/04/integrating-compass-into-eclipse/.

The necessary steps are:

## Create a script which executes the desired Maven command

Create a batch file at the root of your project (eg. ${PROJECT_ROOT}/sass_build.bat), next to the pom.xml, containing the following code

```
call mvn sass:update-stylesheets
```

## Configure Eclipse to execute the script every time you save your SCSS file

1. If not already, open the project property window (Project > Properties), and navigate to the Builders section.
2. Click [New…]
3. A dialog titled ‘Choose configuration type‘ will appear. Select ‘Program‘, and [OK].
4. The ‘Edit Configuration’ window will appear for the builder settings. Name the new builder something relevant – in this case I used ‘SASS Build';
5. The tabbed sections with notes:

   - **Main** page configures the external program

     - Location: path to the batch script. This must either be within the environment path (as set in the Environment page), or be the full path. Eg.[${PROJECT_ROOT}/sass_build.bat] in my case.
     - Working directory: the project path where you want sass to operate. Eg. [${PROJECT_ROOT}]
   - The next TAB **Refresh** specifies what you want to do after the program has finished compiling. I would like Eclipse to recognize the updated css files!

     - ‘Refresh resources upon completion‘ is [checked]
     - ‘Specific resources‘ is set to the output folder where the css files are saved to. Eg. [${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/webapp/css]
   - **Environment** allows you to set specific variables applicable to the command line or your application (no changes needed)
   - **Build Options** – what triggers this builder? Plus miscellaneous.

     - ‘Allocate console‘ [checked] so we can see the results in the console panel
     - Run the builder: [After a clean], [During manual builds], and [During auto builds].
     - ‘Specify working set of relevant resources‘ [checked] – set this to the sass source folders - in my case, [${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/main/resources/scss]. Any changes found in this folder will trigger this builder.
6. When all done, [OK] the configuration. The new builder should appear as the last item of the list.
7. Make sure that Project > Build Automatically has been ticked in the menu to enable automatic compiling.

Test your creation. Modify the SCSS file and save it. Eclipse should pick up the change, compile the SCSS file to a CSS file and place it in the correct destination folder. With any luck, Tomcat will pick up the change and deploy the changed resource.